# Can I delay the showing of a modal dialog in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have some custom code which hooks into native Bootstrap modal functionality and allows for the fetching of content via AJAX and displaying it in the called modal. Here is the code that displays the modal on the AJAX success callback:

```
//Insert content into modal HTML 
$modalContent.html(json.data);

//A bit of custom code here... 

//Display modal
$modal.modal();
```

I would like to improve this action by reducing the perceived lag when clicking on a remote modal link by opening the modal backdrop with a small loading message straight away, and then in the AJAX success callback I'l open the actual modal window. Is there any way to achieve this (specifically is there any way to programatically show a modals' backdrop first and then defer the showing of the modal window to a later time?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like so

```
function getModal(){
    $.ajax(...).success(function(){
        $modalContent.html(json.data);
        $modal.modal();
    });
}

function showSpinner(){
    //show div with spinner
}

function showModalOnClick(){
    openEmptyModal();
    showSpinner();
    getModal();
}

$(...).onclick(showModalOnClick);
```

Comment: I would like to prevent the user from clicking on any other remote modals while the AJAX modal is loading, so the loading div would be full page. I was really hoping I can programatically control the the corresponding modal's backdrop and insert the loader there, or at least replace the modal backdrops styling before it's shown so that I can display a custom backdrop and retain the original backdrop so a person can close the modal by clicking outside the dialog

Comment: You can choose where the spinner is located. if you want the spinner to only be in the modal you can open the empty model first, then show the spinner and then do the ajax request.

Comment: If you don't want another remote modal to open when a different one is open, you can also check if there is already one open before you do the ajax call.